# Store listings in additional languages will use an icon from the package(s) in this submission

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am trying to submit my application to store, and in the "Manage Store listing languages" section i am getting the following error "Store listings in additional languages will use an icon from the package(s) in this submission." and i am not able to submit app to store.
I am getting following screen when i click manage store listing languages.[image]

and i am selecting required languages like English. But, still it is not accepting.
What to do? 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you create Store listings for additional language, you will have a Store listing page for each one. So you will need to upload images for each language separately (even if you are using the same images),and provide captions to use for each language.

For more details, see [App screenshots and images](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-screenshots-and-images#app-tile-icon).

Also, I think this error could be caused by the app tile icon.
If your submission only includes UWP packages, you don't have to provide this image. But it's highly recommended if your app also targets on Windows Phone 8.1 or earlier. The app tile icon is used when displaying your app's Store listing to customers on Windows Phone 8.1 and earlier.

And customers on Windows Phone 8.1 or earlier will see a blank icon with your app's listing, if you don't provide this image.

What's more, the app tile icon has to be a .png file measuring 300 x 300 pixels.